# How do you get the control/view or the page is not cleaned xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xamarin

I keep all ViewModel in the IOC. and the page is reloaded and leaving the page 
creates a new instance and everything is empty , at first I thought that maybe the page , too, I need to keep in a container , but then noticed that for example ListView is on the page , despite reload the page , it is made a singleton ?
The question is where the problem lies , in my custom elements and control, that they are not singletons , or that the page is reloaded each time ?

Comment: Please describe your question well and add some reference code also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea behind it is very simple. The data is not being stored in the page since when you navigate to the page, a new instance of the page is being created.

You can do so by maintaining a **static instance** of the page. ie the page is created only the first time the application is run. The next time you load the page, the state will be maintained.

If you're using prism, go to the main view which handles the navigation/tile navigation. In that for each screen a new object might be getting created. If you create a static instance of each view in the main view, we can ensure that the data will not be lost, since the static instance is created only once throughout the application.

Hope you got the point. Revert if any more doubts.

Comment: I have  custom control and ListView on page.If reloading the page is normal, then the problem is in the Binding?

Comment: That is, the page itself does not display anything

Comment: ListView is a singleton ? if it is not cleaned properly or 
Correctly made ​​bindings ?

Comment: I hope you did not get the point. I hope you have many sub views for your main view, ie if the sub views are static the data can be maintained. In my project also I have like many sub views. Some subview I may need to keep the data, ie it requires reloading only when data changes and not on screen load. While some pages requires to be loaded each time a user enters the page. So such page instances can be created new each time the navigation is done or page is loaded.

Comment: **List view singleton in what sense?** List view is a component in a view and it is reloaded when a new instance of the view is created.